# catch all domain requests for python web app (Flask) with apache

Tags: python, docker, apache, flask, docker-compose

The current situation is that I have a flask app which runs like a charm if I send my requests to the IP address of the server or docker container.
The app runs in a docker container with ubuntu 18.04 and apache2.4.

This container is implemented in my local development environment where all other apps running in docker containers as well. All containers sharing the same network. So they are able to communicate.

The main problem is that the especially the container which includes the python app only responds if I call it by its IP address. If I call it by its domain name (docker-compose generated) the apache responds with a error 400 and bad request.

That means the container receives the request and led it to the apache but the apache cannot route it to the default virtualhost.

I've tried some things but nothing worked.

- ServerName localhost and ServerAlias *
- ServerName null and ServerAlias *
- Without ServerName and ServerAlias

My current .conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    #ServerName null
    #ServerAlias *

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    WSGIDaemonProcess basicflaskapp user=bflaskappuser group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/BasicFlaskApp/BasicFlaskApp.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/BasicFlaskApp>
        WSGIProcessGroup basicflaskapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading on
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        # For Apache 2.4
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/BasicFlaskApp/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the one and only .conf. There is no other .conf which could be used.
That means for me that this .conf will be default.

I won't define a fixed domain name because it changed sometimes in my development and production development.

Does anybody has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Does your hostname contain underscore characters?

Comment: In my local environment yes, but if I deploy the container to AWS I have a FQDN only with dots because of an subdomain. And both doesn't work.